# how to extends multiple class in react js

Tags: reactjs

how to extend multiple class child component in reactjs?

```
//this is one component 
import  React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
class Apicomponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.sate={};
        this.ibios=this.ibios.bind(this);
    }
    ibios(e){
        var prametars={
               "firstName":"venkaiah"
          }     
        return prametars;
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <p>hi...</p>
            );
    }
}

export default Apicomponent;
//another component
import  React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Apicomponent from './IBIOS';

class IbiosGetComponent extends Apicomponent{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.sate={};
        this.apiCallFunction=this.apiCallFunction.bind(this);
    }
    apiCallFunction(){
        var apCallfunction=this.ibios();
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <p>hi...</p>
            );
    }
}

export default IbiosGetComponent;
```

//how to extends multiple class

```
import React from 'react';
import ChartComponent from './ChartComponents';
import IbiosGetComponent from '../IBIOS/ApiCalls';

class BarChartComponent extends ChartComponent,IbiosGetComponent{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={}
    }
 componentDidMount(){
    var parmsfromibios=this.IbiosGetComponent.apiCallFunction();
        console.log(parmsfromibios)
}
render(){
     return(<p>hi....</p>)
}
export default BarChartComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouls use keyword 'super' to access the inherited class,

```
apiCallFunction(){
        var apCallfunction = super.ibios();
    }
```